# Subquery in a Lambda Expression or LINQ

Tags: c#, linq, lambda

How can you write this query using a lambda expression or LINQ:

```
SELECT    *
FROM      vehicles 
WHERE     (memo1 like '%CERTIFIED%' OR memo2 = 'CERTIFIED')
AND       stockno IN (SELECT stockno FROM udealer2 where ACC='UCERT')
ORDER BY  model, days DESC
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Not knowing much about your model, here is a blind mechanical translation of your query:

```
vehicles.Where( v =>
    (SqlMethods.Like(v.memo1, "%CERTIFIED%") || v.memo2 == "CERTIFIED") &&
    udealer2.Any(d => d.ACC == "UCERT" && d.stockno == v.stockno)
).OrderBy(v => v.model)
.ThenByDescending(v => v.days)
```

Answer (score 3):

```
where Dealers.Any(d => d.Account == "UCERT" && something.StockNo == d.StockNo)
```